# Is there an established procedure for titanium tetrachloride titration?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, titration

I’m attempting to do an aldol reaction with $\ce{TiCl4}$ as the catalyst. It worked well in the large scale ($100~\mathrm{mg}$) test system but not, so far, in my $5~\mathrm{mg}$ scale actual system. Our bottle of $\ce{TiCl4}$ is not the youngest, the seal has $\ce{TiO2}$ precipitates on the inner side, and when you finally manage to stick a needle from the argon line in, you almost get a geyser of hydrochloric acid steam — need I mention that the liquid is cloudy from precipitated $\ce{TiO2}$?

My supervisor said distillation is not an option due to unremovable residues of $\ce{TiO2}$ getting stuck in the distillation apparatus. But I would love to know what purity the $\ce{TiCl4}$ still has and thus how much I should upscale it when adding it to the reaction.

Are there any rather simple titration methods for $\ce{TiCl4}$ known or established like they are for *n*-butyllithium?

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{TiCl4}$ is amenable to distillation if done carefully so as to exclude moisture. That doesn't mean it isn't a pain, however.

We do a lot of chemistry using $\ce{TiCl4}$ and other Ti Lewis acids (including some Ti aldol reactions on v. small scale), so end up having to distill it quite often (roughly once a quarter). Once distilled, it lasts in the fridge until it runs out so long as the flask is well sealed and everyone remembers to flush with argon before they're finished using it.

I'll quote from *Purification of Laboratory chemicals* for general information, but also note that we don't follow this procedure. (Mercury makes me uncomfortable)

> [image: Purification of titanium tetrachloride]
>   **Ref:** ['Purification of Laboratory Chemicals', 6 ed.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/book/9781856175678)

In practice, we simply distill the $\ce{TiCl4}$ under reduced pressure (high vacuum pump), discarding the first few mL as would be common procedure. This *usually* yields $\ce{TiCl4}$ that is clear in colour and sufficiently **pure** for our chemistry. If some colour remains, a second distillation from copper turnings is occasionally done, but this is rarely needed.

The key bit of information is to make sure that you quench all of the glassware and tubing used with a weak base (sodium hydrogen carbonate is sufficient), and to ensure that the pump exhausts into a good fume cupboard incase any fumes do escape. All of the glassware used should also be heavily dried prior to use.

---

Comment: > sufficiently dry | $\ce{TiCl4}$ may be not dry? How so?

Comment: Well we can't do Karl Fisher type work on it to identify moisture content (to my knowledge).   This kind of Aldol chemistry is very sensitive to water, especially on a small scale, so any water present would quench the enolate and our chemistry wouldn't work. This suggests to me its 'sufficiently' dry, especially as we're using it for the same purpose as Jan.

Comment: Let me expand the reason for my uncertainty. $\ce{TiCl4}$ reacts with water, producing solid $\ce{TiO2}$ and gaseous $\ce{HCl}$. I highly doubt any moisture may exist in $\ce{TiCl4}$. So, I repeat - how $\ce{TiCl4}$ may be wet?

Comment: Edited the post to reflect your comment, my initial answer was perhaps worded a little unclearly.